# iOS Sharing of Base Map file between several apps

Tags: ios, arcgis-ios

I am new to iOS development and looking for general advice on how to achieve the following situation:

We have developed our first iOS mapping application using the Agentry platform. The application uses the ArcGIS iOS SDK for mapping functionality and we included a base map file for offline use that is over 1GB in size.

Now the second app request has come in for similar functionality and we are wondering whether it is possible to somehow share the base map file so that we do not have to have another 1+ GB app.

I know the security limitations of iOS make sharing of files a little more difficult, but is this type of approach possible? I have looked a little into iOS extensibility SDK to see if that is an option but I am not really sure where to begin.

Comment: This sounds more about iOS development than GIS, you might have more luck getting this migrated to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

If your basemap is in mbtiles SQLite 3 format then you can use it any many apps and mapping development platforms and mapping/gis applications. If it's using ESRI TPK then you'r out of luck. Use QGIS with the QMetaTiles Plugin to produce your mbtiles or gdal_translate or gdal2tiles_parallel.py